# ExactTarget, Automations, Folders and API

Tags: soap, fuel-sdk, c#, automation, folder

This is a three-part question:

In the Automation Studio, automations are arranged in folders. However, unlike with all other types of objects I have managed up until now with SOAP and Fuel using the C# librairy, I haven't been able to figure out how to create an automation within a specific folder. There isn't any `CategoryID` or `FolderID` in the `FuelSDK.Automation` class. Is there any hope at all to achieve this with the API ? Perhaps with a separate request ? I find it odd that I can retrieve the folders for the content type *automations* using a `FilterPart` object but cannot create content into them.

Also, there doesn't seem to be any way of **listing** the automations, with or without a `FilterPart` object. It seems it's only possible to retrieve a single Automation at a time. Is there a way of obtaining a **list** of automations ? This is possible at least for data extensions, emails, queries and folders.

Lastly, I haven't found any way of obtaining the tasks and activities of an automation. Is there any way to achieve this ?

Everything goes smoothly, if slowly, for data extensions, queries, emails and send definitions, if one sticks to using SOAP. Automations have been very frustrating to deal with. If any of the things I am asking for are impossible, I would like to know as soon as possible.

Thank you.